# How to get the IPV4 address of a computer in the network through cmd?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line

I've always used the `tracert` and `ping` commands to obtain the IPV4 address of my computers. 
Now I seem unable to do so:

```
C:\>tracert win7x64

Tracing route to WIN7X64 [fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  WIN7X64 [fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc]

Trace complete.

C:\>ping win7x64

Pinging WIN7X64 [fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::f44f:fb88:3026:4ecc%53:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Is there a windows command to obtain the IPV4 address of one computer in the network by knowing its name only? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do `ping -4 win7x64` to get the IPv4 ip address.

For traceroute you can use `tracert -4 win7x64`.

From `ping /?`:

```
Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
            [-r count] [-s count] [[-j host-list] | [-k host-list]]
            [-w timeout] [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name
Options:
    -4             Force using IPv4.
```

And from `tracert /?`:

```
Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout]
               [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name
Options:
    -4                 Force using IPv4.
```